# How should I handle an multiple-inheritance conflict of types rather than methods?

Tags: c++, typedef, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have:

```
class A { public: using foo_t = int; }
class B { public: using foo_t = int; }
class C : public A, public B { }
```

I want to refer to `C::foo_t`. Yes, it has to be `C::foo_t`, not `C::A::foo_t`  nor `C::B::foo_t`. Obviously, the compiler complains about ambiguity. If these were methods, I could use virtual inheritance and maybe a mixin to form a diamond or what-not. But what should I do for types? Should I just manually add a using statement?

**Notes:**

- You may assume I statically assert both foo_t's are the same.

Comment: Why not `using foo_t = A::foo_t`?

Comment: Where is your diamond inheritance? I can only see multiple inheritance, C inherits from A and B.

Comment: [Diamond inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) only possible with at least 4 classes.

Comment: @Janosimas: I could form a diamond to maybe resolve the conflict if these were methods. Edited to clarify that and removed diamond from the title.

Answer (score 4):

Using statement is enough indeed:

```
class A { public: using foo_t = int; };
class B { public: using foo_t = int; };
class C : public A, public B { public: using A::foo_t; };

int main() {
    C::foo_t v = 0;
}
```

This way, `C::foo_t` is definitely `A::foo_t` (as correctly suggested in the comments).
If you want to define the `foo_t` type or a new type for `C` instead, you can do that as it follows:

```
class C : public A, public B { public: using bar_t = A::foo_t; };
```

Here is a minimal, complete example where the types are verified to be the same using *sfinae* instead of a *static assertion*:

```
#include<type_traits>

class A { public: using foo_t = int; };
class B { public: using foo_t = int; };
class C { public: using foo_t = double; };

template<class T, class U,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename T::foo_t, typename U::foo_t>::value>* = nullptr>
class D: public T, public U { public: using T::foo_t; };

int main() {
    D<A, B>::foo_t v = 0;
    // the line below does not compile
    //D<A, C>::foo_t v = 0;
}
```

Comment: Added the accessors.

Comment: I know it's enough, but is it the Right Thing (TM)?

Comment: You want `C` to expose a type. What type? This is a reasonable way to define it and, of course, this is *a right one*.

Comment: If what you want to express is "`C::foo_t` is `A::foo_t`", definitely.